# The Inner Product of In and Out Spins

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space

In *Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum*, Hrabovsky and Susskind define the *in* and *out* vector like this:
$$
| i \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | u \rangle + \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} | d \rangle \\~\\
| o \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | u \rangle - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} | d \rangle \\~\\
$$

We are asked to prove $ \langle i | o \rangle = 0$. Simple enough, but when we perform the multiplication:

$$
\frac{1}{2} \langle u | u \rangle - \frac{i^2}{2} \langle d | d \rangle \\~\\
\frac{1}{2} \langle u | u \rangle + \frac{1}{2} \langle d | d \rangle \\~\\
= 1 \: \text{if} \langle u | d \rangle \: \text{and} \: \langle d | d \rangle \: \text{are both positive and constant.}
$$
This certainly isn't zero! What are we missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful in a complex vector space.
$$\langle i|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\langle u|-\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\langle d|$$
so you forgot to take the complex conjugate.

The result is immediate after that.